How to Ensure Consistency in Fingerprint Data Capture Using Morpho Device?
We have purchased a Morpho Device and are using it to capture fingerprint data for authorization during valid user logins on the system.
For example, once a user registers with valid data, they reauthorize using their fingerprint biometric data.
However, we are facing an issue where the same fingerprint scanning process yields different data at times. How can we resolve this?
For Ex - Same finger data 1=
$postdata2 = "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";

For Ex - Same finger data 2 =
$base64Data = "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";

Both are different.
We are trying to re-authrise the fingere print data and and if same user try to login proceed this.
